# Ruby / Selenium issue identifying displayed items in a list

Tags: ruby, selenium

I'm trying to understand what is going on in my attempt to identify which elements in a list are visible.

The application uses variable menu dropdowns where a standard list of options exists, but the options that are visible on each row of the application varies based on certain parameters.

[image: example of menu dropdown]

So, for the example above, the HTML looks like...

```
    <ul>
        <li id="liAddResource" style="display: list-item;"></li>
        <li id="liEditResource" style="display: none;"></li>
        <li id="liAddBarrier" style="display: none;"></li>
        <li id="liEditBarrier" style="display: none;"></li>
        <li id="liRemoveTask" style="display: list-item;"></li>
        <li id="liRemoveResource" style="display: none;"></li>
        <li id="liRemoveBarrier" style="display: none;"></li>
    </ul>
```

As you can see, the two items that are displayed, have a display style, where the others are "none".

My thought was to grab all of the list items and then cycle through them to determine which options are displayed.

```
    buttons=@driver.find_elements(xpath: button_path)
    puts "verify_displayed_action_buttons:  Buttons are:")
    buttons.each_with_index do |b,i|
      puts "     Button: #{i}"
      puts "               Label:#{b.text}"
      id=b.attribute('id')
      puts "               ID: #{id}"
      displayed=b.displayed?
      puts "               Displayed Status: #{displayed}"
    end
```

However, using this method, only the first of the two options showed up as displayed.

```
 Button: 0
           Label:Add Resource
           ID: liAddResource
           Displayed Status: true
 Button: 1
           Label:
           ID: liEditResource
           Displayed Status: false
 Button: 2
           Label:
           ID: liAddBarrier
           Displayed Status: false
 Button: 3
           Label:
           ID: liEditBarrier
           Displayed Status: false
 Button: 4
           Label:
           ID: liRemoveTask
           Displayed Status: false
 Button: 5
           Label:
           ID: liRemoveResource
           Displayed Status: false
 Button: 6
           Label:
           ID: liRemoveBarrier
           Displayed Status: false
```

However, if before checking the status of each item, I click the ellipses and force the menu to reload, I get the appropriate results.

```
    puts "verify_displayed_action_buttons:  Buttons are:"
    buttons.each_with_index do |b,i|
    #click on the ellipses to repaint the menu
    action_cell=@driver.find_element(id: ellipses_id)
    action_cell.click
    buttons=@driver.find_elements(xpath: button_path)
      b=buttons[i]
      puts "     Button: #{i}"
      puts "               Label:#{b.text}"
      id=b.attribute('id')
      puts "               ID: #{id}"
      displayed=b.displayed?
      puts "               Displayed Status: #{displayed}"
    end
```

Output - status for Button 4 is now displayed.

```
 Button: 0
           Label:Add Resource
           ID: liAddResource
           Displayed Status: true
 Button: 1
           Label:
           ID: liEditResource
           Displayed Status: false
 Button: 2
           Label:
           ID: liAddBarrier
           Displayed Status: false
 Button: 3
           Label:
           ID: liEditBarrier
           Displayed Status: false
 Button: 4
           Label:Remove Task
           ID: liRemoveTask
           Displayed Status: true
 Button: 5
           Label:
           ID: liRemoveResource
           Displayed Status: false
 Button: 6
           Label:
           ID: liRemoveBarrier
           Displayed Status: false
```

It is acting as if interrogating the display status of the first element resulting from the find_elements call somehow changes the status of the later elements.

Any advice on what is going on here and how I might be able to do this without clicking on the icon to make the menu regenerate each time would be appreciated.  This action is taken many thousands of times during a full regression test and it would be very costly having to do this each time I want to check it.

Update - I should also add that I did try to access the list items directly via their IDs but the results were the same.  Unless I click regenerate the menu each time, only the first button checked ever gives me a status of displayed.

Answer (score 1):

Selenium Webdriver can only interact with things that are visible on the page. This will be why you have to click the ellipsis before iterating through the available options. This is also why you're not getting the label text for the elements that are not visible.

Comment: I definitely get that concept, thanks David.  But here's where I get confused.  When I do the find_elements and bring them all back, there are two buttons that are visible, #1 and #4.  If I check the .displayed? status of either one, I will get a 'true' response.  But if I check two of them in succession, I get a 'true' on the first response and a 'false' on the second response.  Why would the visible status of the 2nd element change just by checking the visible status of the first element?  Any insights would be great.

Comment: What output do you get if you do `puts buttons.each.map(&:displayed?)`. Using the html you gave in your question I get `true false false false true false false` which is correct.